# wso2 log on Stackify connector

Tags: wso2, stackify

I would like to have posibility to log message (info , debug or error ) from sequences ..

My scenario would be in a case of error call Error Sequence and in it I would call (proxy, or connector ) to log custome message.

I'm thinking of **Stackify** 
http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/categories/200398739-Errors-Logs

is it possible or anyone can point me in correct direction how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What would you like to do with the log? Is it not possible to get it in the existing logs (with log4j) using the embeded log mediator. Then when you have it on your machine, you could use loggly, elk, or logstash... to centralize and analyze the logs and create alerting if required.

Comment: I want to be notify when error happens, in office we are using stackify for logging for web apps and already has setup email notifier. So my idea was to simply from wso2, in a case of error just ,publish/push message into Stakify (maybe using web method on it's server) and get that message over email ...

Answer (score 0):

If your already using Retrace (Stackify) on the server and capturing the error itself you can do this via an error log monitor with a notification group containing just yourself.

1. Create the notification group with yourself in it
2. Find the error in the error dashboard and filter down to just that error is showing (usually done by filtering for specific message text in combination with app and environment filters)
3. Save the query (top right corner of screen, save icon), name it something you find appropriate and descriptive.
4. Go to the log monitors screen and add a new log monitor, use the saved query. Set it to alert after 1x looking back an hour (to give you time to go see it) and run it every minute or 5 minutes.
5. Set your notification group as send at the alert level you chose (or all levels)

Hope that helps.

(Edit after some thoughts)
you can do the same thing from any log message by the way, whether its an INFO, ERROR, DEBUG, etc...  all you need is to filter it down to get to what you want, save the query and create a monitor for it.